# Dataframe multiplication to create adjacency matrix

Tags: python, dataframe, adjacency-matrix

I am trying to create an **adjacency matrix** from an excel file that lists the IDs of school projects, their types, assigned students, their roles in the project, and their gender shown below:

[![sample data][1]][1]

I want to generate a 12x12 matrix *M* using pandas such that for any two students *x* and *y*, *M[x][y]=z*, where *z* denotes the **number of projects** on which both students *x* and *y* have worked on. Below is my code which gives me NaN all over:

```
import pandas as pd

df  = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
df1 = pd.crosstab(df.project_id, df.student_id)
df2 = df1 * df1.T
print(df2)
```

My output is:

[![Output][2]][2]

I am very new to python and do not know how to fix this problem.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEQU6.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4ICr.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly use `crosstab`, this will only give you the combinations of students and projects.

What you can do is first perform a `merge` of the DataFrame with itself on `"project_id"` to get all combinations of students per project, then use `crosstab`:

```
df2 = df.merge(df, on='project_id', suffixes=('1','2'))

pd.crosstab(df2['student_id1'], df2['student_id2'])
```

*NB. be careful, the intermediate dataframe `df2` will have add many rows as there are combinations of students per project!.*

Example input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'project_id': ['P1', 'P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P3', 'P3'],
                   'student_id': [1,2,3,4,1,2]})
```

Output:

```
student_id2  1  2  3  4
student_id1            
1            2  2  0  1
2            2  2  0  1
3            0  0  1  0
4            1  1  0  1
```

##### alternatives

Another approach using python sets (slower but more memory efficient);

```
s = df.groupby('student_id')['project_id'].agg(set)
a = s.to_numpy()
out = pd.DataFrame(a&a[:, None], index=s.index, columns=s.index).applymap(len)
```

Or:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

s = df.groupby('student_id')['project_id'].agg(set)

df2 = pd.Series([len(a&b) for a,b in combinations_with_replacement(s, 2)],
                index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(combinations_with_replacement(s.index, 2))).unstack()

out = df2.combine_first(df2.T).convert_dtypes()
```